# Java Substring based on condtion

Tags: java, substring

I'm pretty new to Java and I would like to know if there is an effective way of creating a substring based on conditions.

Currently I am reading from a txt file and changing that txt file to a String format using BufferedReader.

I am receiving several txt files but they all have the same format.
The data that I want to extract is always on the 45th row.
And the 45th row of the txt file always look something like this.

```
number : abcd
```

I want to extract the "abcd" part.
It would be appreciated if anyone could tell me if there is any way to do this.

Comment: so you want to loop through the file until row 45? and then split based upon a colon ?

Comment: Yes all the data before and after the 45th row is unnecessary and I want the string that comes after the colon!

Comment: So two problems, which have you tried so far and what problems have you found?

Comment: Use a [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp) to call [BufferedReader.readline()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) 45 times. At the 45th iteration, use [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to split the line by colon.

Comment: `System.out.println("number : abcd".split(" : ")[1]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file at specific line and Regex for the desired data:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try{
                String line45 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.txt")).get(44);

                String pattern = "\\: (.*)"; // Capture everything after ':' colon character

                Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
                Matcher m = r.matcher(line45);
                if (m.find( )) {
                    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
                }

        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("entry not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
Found value: abcd
```

Assign `m.group(1)` to a variable and use the data as needed.

Comment: Beware if the file is large, readAllLines may unnecessarily waste memory and IO throughput.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String s = stringFromTextFile;
s = s.split(":")[1];
s = s.substring(1, s.length());
System.out.println("Abcd: " + s);
```

The line `s = s.split(":")[1]` essentially makes an array of the 2 elements. For example, entry 0 would be 'number ', and entry 1 would be ' abcd'.
Then, `s = s.substring(1, s.length())` removes the space at the beginning of ' abcd', turning it into 'abcd'.

Disclaimer: This code is not fully tested, so some errors may occur.

Answer (score -1):

Read the file contents as list of Strings

```
    Files.readAllLines(new File(fileName).toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

and get the 45th element, then split by : and get the second array element.